# Using my Das Keyboard 4 for Mac to change the volume locks the keyboard in caps lock?

Tags: mac, keyboard, capslock

I'm using a Das Keyboard 4 (Blue Switch) on Mac OS X 10.12.6.

I've been having this problem for more than a year now (I bought the keyboard in May of 2016, I can't remember not having this problem to be honest), but only recently figured out how to reliably cause it.

Whenever I use the volume wheel or press mute/unmute on my keyboard, it locks the keyboard in Caps Lock. I can't turn off this locking unless I unplug and replug my keyboard. After I do that, the keyboard's Caps Lock indicator will turn on, and then I can press Caps Lock to turn off Caps Lock.

Changing the volume on my Mac (through the given menu bar and System Preferences interfaces) does not lock my keyboard in Caps Lock.

Any thoughts on why this might be happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this happening just in your Mac? Or this also repeatable in other's Mac? (Because this could be a hardware issue - and you may want to claim warranty against Das)

Comment: @Darius weirdly enough it only happens on my Mac... before when I used an Apple wireless keyboard I'd never get these sort of problems though.

Comment: @Darius I also tested a wired Apple keyboard on my Mac, and changing the volume using that doesn't lock the keyboard in caps lock either, so it seems to be the unfortunate combination of computer and keyboard :/